# Trocando última letra de uma palavra, utilizando o método 'replace()'

Tags: javascript

Estou fazendo um exercício que pede para que eu transforme a palavra *Roberto* em *Roberta* utilizando o método `replace()`, e pela minha lógica essa solução deveria funcionar:

```
var roberto = 'Roberto';

roberto.replace( roberto.charAt(6), 'a' );
// Raberto
```

Utilizando o `charAt()` e passando a posição da letra por parâmetro funciona tranquilamente com todas as outras letras da palavra, porém quando passo a posição 6, que seria justamente a letra que eu preciso (a última no caso) ele pega a segunda letra ao invés da última. Alguém saberia me informar por que isso ocorre?

**OBS.:** A solução **TEM** que ser utilizando o método `replace()`.

Comment: Só uma observação: o charAt(6) é um objeto, então vc teria que convertê-lo para string.

Comment: Seria algo assim:
`var roberto = 'Roberto', op = (roberto.charAt(6)).toString();
roberto.replace(op, 'a');`  e mesmo assim ainda ficaria: `Raberto`, porque o replace simples só é executado no primeiro caracter encontrado.

Comment: Seria o mesmo que `roberto.replace('o', 'a');` para funcionar, você teria que fazer assim: `var roberto = 'Roberto', op = new RegExp((roberto.charAt(6)).toString()+"$", 'gim'); roberto.replace(op, 'a');`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Isso está ocorrendo porque a letra **o** é repetida duas vezes. Uma na posição 2 e a outra na posição 6. Desta forma, o replace irá substituir a primeira ocorrência apenas, e não a segunda ou terceira.

Você não vai conseguir usando textos puros, como o mostrado em seu exemplo. Poderá ter esse mesmo problema várias vezes e não é interessante fazer gambiarras para obter a última ocorrência apenas.

Alternativamente, utilizando o `replace`, poderás usar expressão regular para isso, procurando qualquer caractere no final da string.

```js
var roberto = 'Roberto';

roberto = roberto.replace(/.$/, "a");

console.log(roberto);
```

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente, obrigado @CypherPotato!

Comment: @AugustoVasques perdão, não entendi o questionamento ... ?

Comment: @AugustoVasques ah sim, sem problemas .. rs'

Answer (score 5):

Se é obrigado usar essa função a única forma é usar um RegEx para determinar um padrão que faça o que deseja.

Você não pode passar a posição e não pode só passar qual é o caractere que será trocado porque ele fará isso no primeiro que encontrar.

Então precisa achar um padrão de expressão regular que ache o último caractere para trocar, no caso o `$` faz isso por você.

```js
var roberto = 'Roberto';
console.log(roberto.replace(/o$/, 'a'));
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/String/RegExLastChar.js).

Tem [documentação](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions) para estudar tudo o que dá para fazer com RegEx. É bem poderoso e todo padrão que desejar pode ser achado, mesmo que seja um pouco complexo criar algo assim.

Eu prefiro fazer isso de uma forma mais performática sem usar o `replace()`, justamente por isso e por ser menos legível, mas está aí a solução de acordo com o requisito.

Comment: Você foi mais rápido.

Comment: Mais rápidos q uns, menos rápido q outros...

Comment: O que eu achei engraçado a mesma pessoa negativar a minha e positivar a outra que é a mesma coisa.

Comment: Da vontade de restaurar a minha resposta só para ver se a pessoa iria fazer.

Comment: @AugustoVasques quem negativou tem problemas comigo não com você. E ela se vale de treta antiga pra ficar impune, porque se eu a punir poderia falar que é perseguição minha. Mas ela está cavando um buraco cada vez maior, onde fica difícil dizer que ela não está perseguindo.

Comment: Então se positivasse a minha, a do cyber e o cara negativasse a sua seria muita contradição num voto para relevar. As três são iguais.

Comment: @AugustoVasques é o que o Maniero disse: treta antiga.

Comment: É, esse que dei negativo aqui (diferente do que deu hoje em outra de JS) foi porque eu dei um negativo em resposta dele depois que eu comentei que tinha erro e ele não quis corrigir, mostrei com várias fontes o erro e mesmo assim ele teimou que estava certo. É por essas coisas que é melhor nem comentar, se eu tivesse só negativado ele continuaria me positivando e elogiando publicamente como fazia antes. Algumas pessoas não tem "idade" pra participar de comunidade.